# Which function grows faster: n^2(log n) or n^2?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If n = 100 , then (100)^2(log 100) = 100^2 (2) = 10,000 * 2 = 20,000. As opposed to (100^2) = 10,000.

I am thinking n^2(log n) grows faster because it has a higher value. But I am thinking they are similar since they are multiplied by the same n^2.

What exactly is a good to way to tell which functions grows fast, is it by inputting a large value of n such as 100 for each function?

Comment: *"What exactly is a good to way to tell which functions grows fast"* - if you aren't sure whether a function like n^2 log n is O(n^2), you should apply the definition of O.

Comment: what is `n^2(log n)` actually? do you mean `n^(2*(log n))` which is `(n^2)^(log n)`? or you mean `(n^2)*(log n)`? either is bigger than just `n^2`, for all big enough `n`.

Comment: *"What exactly is a good to way to tell which functions grows fast"* - The best way (i.e. that gives the most correct answer) is to **do the math**.  See Dmitry's answer for an example.  Various other (heuristic or empirical) ways are subject to possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

Function `f` *grows faster* than `g` if

```
lim f(n) / g(n) = +inf
  n -> +inf
```

In your case `f(n) = (n^2) * log(n)` and `g(n) = n^2`

```
lim f(n)/g(n) = lim (n^2) * log(n) / n^2 = lim log(n) = +inf
  n -> +inf       n -> +inf                  n -> +inf
```

so `(n^2) * log(n)` grows faster than `n^2`.

Let's compare `f(n) = n^(2 * log(n))` and `g(n) = n^2`. We have

```
lim n^(2 * log(n)) / n^2 = lim n^(2 * (log(n) - 1)) > /* log(n) > 2 */ >
  n -> +inf                  n -> +inf                       n -> +inf

log n^(2 * (2 - 1)) = log n^2 = +inf
  n -> +inf             n -> +inf
```

so `n^(2 * log(n))` grows faster than `n^2`

Comment: Very interesting but this is not a math forum.